# TFS 2015 Kanban - Database tables? Where did dbo.workitemsare go?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

My work group recently upgraded from TFS 2013 to TFS 2015; and migrated the database to the new environment. We use the TFS kanban for tracking our work, and for allowing customers to see all the possible items in the input queue to vote on which item is worked on next. We had built a custom SSRS report to get this data out of the TFS database for review from our customers... But now that we've upgraded TFS, a table that was integral to this report is now missing? The table which is now missing is dbo.WorkItemsAre.

Is anyone familiar with where/how the TFS kanban items will be tracked after migrating to 2015? It seems like the documentation on the TFS database has always been lacking when I try finding anything on MSDN or a microsoft site.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For customized reports you should use the warehouse database (Tfs_Warehouse). You can find the documentation about work item tables [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244691.aspx#WorkItems).

Or you can use the cube. The documentation about the work item perspective is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244678.aspx).

For data not available in either the warehouse or the cube you can use the RestAPI or the Client API.

The operational databases are not supported by Microsoft. You may also be asked to remove anything you have built against the operational store for any support to be given.

Comment: More than not supported you may be asked to remove any non microsoft queries to gain support...

Comment: Turns out we hadn't configured the warehouse or analysis services on the server for TFS so that's why I wasn't seeing it! We've got this up and running now. Thank you!!!